# Process unicode strings in python

Tags: python, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I am using fasttext pre-trained model based on english wikipedia. It works as expected...

https://github.com/shantanuo/pandas_examples/blob/master/nlp/fasttext_english.ipynb

But when I try the same code with some other language, I get an error as shown on this page...

https://github.com/shantanuo/pandas_examples/blob/master/nlp/fasttext_marathi.ipynb

The error is related to unicode:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 15: invalid start byte
```

I tried to open the file using Raw Binary option. I changed the function load_words_raw in load.py file:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
```

And now I get a different error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'\x00l\x02'

I have no idea how to handle this.

Comment: When you get errors like these, you should print `repr(s)` to the console to see what the string `s` really contains.

Comment: Can you post the result of the execution of "head -n 5001 cc.mr.300.bin  | tail -n 5000 > /tmp/marathi.vec" somewhere we can download it?

Comment: Ok I just compared both vec files, and the marathi.vec file contains binary data and cannot be processed directly, while the english.vec file is pure float numbers represented as plain ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the second line of the notebook file to:

```
#!wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-crawl/cc.mr.300.vec.gz
```

So pointing to the vec file, instead of the bin file:

```
#!wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-crawl/cc.mr.300.bin.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

**byte 0x80 in position 15**. There is a possibility that file may be encoded in UTF-16.
Try this:

```
with open(path, encoding='utf-16') as f:
   // your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
data : str
with open('crawl-D.txt' ,'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

`str` will contains the whole file as `string`.

parse `float` with `float()`.